# SimpleXml can't access children

Tags: php, simplexml

This is a snippet of XML that I'm working with:

```
<category name="pizzas">
    <item name="Tomato &amp; Cheese">
        <price size="small">5.50</price>
        <price size="large">9.75</price>
    </item>
    <item name="Onions">
        <price size="small">6.85</price>
        <price size="large">10.85</price>
    </item>
    <item name="Peppers">
        <price size="small">6.85</price>
        <price size="large">10.85</price>
    </item>
    <item name="Broccoli">
        <price size="small">6.85</price>
        <price size="large">10.85</price>
    </item>
</category>
```

This is what my php looks like:

```
$xml = $this->xml;
$result = $xml->xpath('category/@name');
foreach($result as $element) {
    $this->category[(string)$element] = $element->xpath('item');
}
```

everything works ok except $element->xpath('item');
I also tried using: $element->children(); as well as other xpath queries, but they all return null.
Why can't I access children of a category?

Comment: dude, use `category/item`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to build a tree based on categories, keyed by category name.  To do that, you should change your code to look like this:

```
$xml = $this->xml;

//Here, match the category tags themselves, not the name attribute.
$result = $xml->xpath('category'); 
foreach($result as $element) {
   //Iterate through the categories. Get their name attributes for the 
   //category array key, and assign the item xpath result to that.
   $this->category[(string)$element['name']] = $element->xpath('item');
}
```

With your original code here: `$result = $xml->xpath('category/@name');` your result was the name attribute nodes, which, as attributes, cannot have children.

Now if you simply wanted a list of all items, you could use `$xml->xpath('category/items')`, but that doesn't appear to be what you had wanted.